# Wire placement for Honeywell evohome WiFi Controller power supply socket soldering

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, repair, thermostat

I'd like to solder the wires that have come loose from the socket of the power supply for my Honeywell evohome WiFi Controller but I don't know where the wires need to connect to the socket.

[image: Honeywell evohome WiFi Controller power supply with loose socket and wires]

Grateful for any help as it's pretty cold right now!

Thanks!

Comment: Try googling wire diagram for that model, looks like a 50/50 choice by eye.

Comment: You could assume that red would be positive and go to the center pin of the socket, but... that's not 100%, and you can't be sure that reverse polarity won't damage the device.  It _should_ have reverse polarity protection coming from a big company like Honeywell, but again, not 100%.

Comment: Also, on the connector, the left connection in the picture seems to be a clean break, and the one on the right looks a little more frayed.  Does that help match up the wires?  Does one have a clean break on a soldered portion of the wire?  If this is just a remote, isn't there a manual or hard wired control somewhere?